# Dask regex extract comparison failing with NotImplementedError

Tags: dask

I have a Dask dataframe that looks like this:

```
class1                                  statement             class2              value
<geoentity_Pic_de_Font_Blanca_2986043>  <hasLatitude>         42.64991^^<degrees> 42.64991
<geoentity_Pic_de_Font_Blanca_2986043>  <hasLongitude>        1.53335^^<degrees>  1.53335
<geoentity_Pic_de_Font_Blanca_2986043>  <hasGeonamesEntityId> 2986043             NaN
<geoentity_Pic_de_Font_Blanca_2986043>  rdfs:label            Pic de Font Blanca  NaN
```

I'm trying to check whether the number in `class1` matches the one in `class2` for all the `<hasGeonamesEntityId>` rows; so that I can get rid of those rows, since they would then carry unnecessarily duplicated data.

I tried:

```
df[(df['statement'] == '<hasGeonamesEntityId>') & (df['class1'].str.extract(r'_(\d+)>$') == df['class2'])].head()
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
E:\WPy-3710\python-3.7.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3347             graph = HighLevelGraph.from_collections(name, dsk, dependencies=[self, key])
   3348             return new_dd_object(graph, name, self, self.divisions)
-> 3349         raise NotImplementedError(key)
   3350 
   3351     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

NotImplementedError: Dask DataFrame Structure:
                    0     1
npartitions=442            
                 bool  bool
                  ...   ...
...               ...   ...
                  ...   ...
                  ...   ...
Dask Name: and_, 3978 tasks
```

My `dtypes` are:

```
class1       category
statement    category
class2         object
value        category
```

I'm not sure why this is failing since the `extract` on its own seems to return the correct sub string. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without a reproducible example, but it looks like you're trying to index a Dask DataFrame with another Dask DataFrame, which isn't supported and probably isn't what you want.

Using just pandas

```
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['a1', 'b2', 'c3']})

In [19]: df[df.A.str.extract('(\d)') == '1']
Out[19]:
     A
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  NaN
```

That's because `.str.extract` returns a DataFrame. Set `expand=False` to get a 1D series

```
In [20]: df[df.A.str.extract('(\d)', expand=False) == '1']
Out[20]:
    A
0  a1
```

Which works for Dask as well

```
In [21]: df = dd.from_pandas(df, 2)

In [22]: df[df.A.str.extract('(\d)', expand=False) == '1']
Out[22]:
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                    A
npartitions=1
0              object
2                 ...
Dask Name: getitem, 5 tasks

In [23]: _.compute()
Out[23]:
    A
0  a1
```